# terra raster values lost after projection

Tags: r, raster, terra

values of a SpatRaster are lost after changing the coordinate reference system. I do not see any reasons why.

```
library(terra)

ext <-
  terra::ext(
    9757195,
    9853641,
    734695,
    799794 
  )

r <-
  terra::rast(ext,
              resolution = 2000,
              crs = "EPSG:6933")
```

I create a SpatVector points geometry to then overlay with my raster and identify in which cells of the raster the points fall. This operation is done in a projected CRS.

```
coord_vec <- data.frame( x = c(9849641, 9761195), y = c(795794.8, 738695.7))

coord_vec <- terra::vect(coord_vec, 
                         crs =  "EPSG:6933", geom=c("x", "y"))
r2_ <-
  terra::rasterize(x = coord_vec, y = r)
```

I want to get back to Geodetic coordinate system but then values are lost.

```
r2_proj <- terra::project(x = r2_,
               y = "epsg:4326")
```

r2_ spatraster before projection is

```
> r2_
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 33, 48, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 2000, 2000  (x, y)
extent      : 9757195, 9853195, 734695, 800695  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / NSIDC EASE-Grid 2.0 Global (EPSG:6933) 
source      : memory 
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :     1 
max value   :     1
```

After projection, values are lost.

```
> r2_proj 
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 27, 52, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.01927436, 0.01927436  (x, y)
extent      : 101.1252, 102.1275, 5.768228, 6.288636  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : memory 
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :   NaN 
max value   :   NaN
```

This workflow has been tested for many datasets of points and extent, so this unexpected output seems to be generated by these values of points and extent.

When I set gdal to FALSE, I then obtain non-null values, hence it seems to result from the GDAL-warp algorithm.

```
terra::project(x = r2_,
               y = "epsg:4326", gdal = F)

> terra::project(x = r2_,
+                y = "epsg:4326", gdal = F)
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 27, 52, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.01927436, 0.01927436  (x, y)
extent      : 101.1252, 102.1275, 5.768228, 6.288636  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : memory 
name        : lyr.1 
min value   :   0.5 
max value   :   0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is mysterious. Perhaps you can [raise an issue](https://github.com/rspatial/terra).

But for what you want to achieve, it would be better to do it like this anyway. That is, avoid transforming raster data, and rasterize to the raster you want.

```
library(terra)
ext <-  ext( 9757195, 9853641, 734695, 799794  )
r <- rast(ext, resolution = 2000, crs = "EPSG:6933")
 
coord_vec <- data.frame( x = c(9849641, 9761195), y = c(795794.8, 738695.7))
coord_vec <- vect(coord_vec, crs="EPSG:6933", geom=c("x", "y"))

v <- project(coord_vec, "epsg:4326")
# project the raster template by using rast(r)
r2 <- project(rast(r), "epsg:4326")
r2 <- rasterize(v, r2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you are reprojecting a raster, there is a resampling process linked to it. When you have the argument 'GDAL=TRUE', it uses the Nearest Neighbor method by default, so it can make sense if your raster is mostly composed by NaNs and few 1s. Alternatively, when you have 'GDAL=FALSE', it uses a bilinear interpolation. If you want to keep the 1s, you could consider using 'maximum' method.